# Yajra Datatables edit print layout

Tags: php, laravel, layout, printing, yajra-datatable

I am new to PHP and laravel programming. Currently, I have built an app that shows the Opening Purchase Orders of my company to show to our vendors.

My company used SAP B1 and Hana as its database.
I used Odbc and successfully connected and show the data to my web app.

Then I used Yajra DataTables to show my Data (for pagination, filter, sorting, etc)
I did it by creating a view named PoTableView.blade.php and putting all the CSS, js source in the HTML tag. Call the scripts at the bottom.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <!-- CSS for Datatable and button   -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.0.1/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.3/css/select.dataTables.min.css">
       
    <!-- JS for Datatable and button   -->
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.0.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.0.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.0.1/js/buttons.print.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.0.1/js/buttons.colVis.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.3/js/dataTables.select.min.js'></script>

</head>

<body> 
    <!-- Show table here   -->
    <div class="table-responsive">
    <table id="myTable" class="display table" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>PO_NUM</td>
            <td>LINE_NUM</td>
            <td>Vendor</td>
            <td>ItemCode</td>
            <td>Description</td>
            <td>UNIT</td>
            <td>QTY</td>
            <td>OPEN_QTY</td>
            <td>Pick Quantity</td>
            <td>ShipDate</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
        @php
            $out = "<tbody>";
            while($row = odbc_fetch_array($query))
            {
                $out .= "<tr>";
                $out .= "<td>".$row['PO_NUM']."</td>";                 
                $out .= "<td>".$row['LINE_NUM']."</td>"; 
                $out .= "<td>".$row['Vendor']."</td>"; 
                $out .= "<td>".$row['ItemCode']."</td>"; 
                $out .= "<td>".$row['Description']."</td>"; 
                $out .= "<td>".$row['UNIT']."</td>"; 
                $out .= "<td>".$row['QTY']."</td>"; 
                $out .= "<td>".$row['OPEN_QTY']."</td>";                 
                $out .= "<td><input type='number' name='PickQty' min='0' max =".$row['OPEN_QTY']." value=".$row['OPEN_QTY']." step='0.01'></td>";
                $out .= "<td>".$row['ShipDate']."</td>"; 
                $out .= "</tr>";
            }
            $out .= "</tbody>";
            echo $out;
        @endphp
    </table> 
    </div>
</body>

<!-- apply Yajra datatables to html table-->
<!-- make table available for sorting and filterring-->
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#myTable').dataTable(
    {
        dom: 'Blfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copy',
            'excel',
            'pdf',            
            {
                extend: 'print',
                text: 'Print selected',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: ':visible'
                }
            },
            'colvis',
            {
                extend: 'print',
                text: 'Print all',
                exportOptions: {
                    modifier: {
                        selected: null
                    }
                }
            },
            {
            text :'My custom button',
            action: function () {
                return view('transactions.print');
                }
            },
        ],
        select: true,        
        scrollY:        '70vh',
        scrollX:       true,
        scrollCollapse: true,
        lengthMenu: [[10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]],
        pagingType: "full_numbers",
    });

});
</script>

</html>
```

result:
[image]

The problem is when I pressed print or export button. the value of the input column (Pick Quantity) will be empty

[image]

Otherwise, there are some columns that I want to hide from the printing process. So I would like to know how can I edit the print layout.

As you can see, I tried to add another custom button with a simple action that open a new view but it seems not working.

Please help.

**Update solution**
Have helped from Rushikesh Ganesh, I can print out the value of the input. But I met another problem that after user changed the values in input fields. I still print out the old values.
So I have set id for every input cell by changing somes lines

```
@php
            $out = "<tbody>";
            $r = 0;
            while($row = odbc_fetch_array($query))
            {
                $out .= "<tr>";
                $out .= "<td>".$row['PO_NUM']."</td>";                 
                $out .= "<td>".$row['LINE_NUM']."</td>"; 
                $out .= "<td>".$row['Vendor']."</td>"; 
                $out .= "<td>".$row['ItemCode']."</td>"; 
                $out .= "<td>".$row['Description']."</td>"; 
                $out .= "<td>".$row['UNIT']."</td>"; 
                $out .= "<td>".$row['QTY']."</td>"; 
                $out .= "<td>".$row['OPEN_QTY']."</td>";                 
                $out .= "<td><input type='number' id='PickQty".$r."' min='0' max =".$row['OPEN_QTY']." value =".$row['OPEN_QTY']." step='0.01' onchange='updateValue(this)'></td>";
                $out .= "<td>".$row['ShipDate']."</td>"; 
                $out .= "</tr>";
                $r+=1;
            }
            $out .= "</tbody>";
            echo $out;
        @endphp
```

and then write the function updateValue(this) within javascript

```
function updateValue(e) {
var current = document.getElementById(e.id);
current.setAttribute("value",e.value);
};
```

full code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <!-- CSS for Datatable and button   -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.0.1/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.3/css/select.dataTables.min.css">
       
    <!-- JS for Datatable and button   -->
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.0.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.0.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.0.1/js/buttons.print.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.0.1/js/buttons.colVis.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.3/js/dataTables.select.min.js'></script>

</head>

<body> 
    <!-- Show variable for debug here   -->
    <p id="PickQty0"></p>
    <!-- Show table here   -->
    <div class="table-responsive">
    <table id="myTable" class="display table" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>PO_NUM</td>
            <td>LINE_NUM</td>
            <td>Vendor</td>
            <td>ItemCode</td>
            <td>Description</td>
            <td>UNIT</td>
            <td>QTY</td>
            <td>OPEN_QTY</td>
            <td>Pick Quantity</td>
            <td>ShipDate</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
        @php
            $out = "<tbody>";
            $r = 0;
            while($row = odbc_fetch_array($query))
            {
                $out .= "<tr>";
                $out .= "<td>".$row['PO_NUM']."</td>";                 
                $out .= "<td>".$row['LINE_NUM']."</td>"; 
                $out .= "<td>".$row['Vendor']."</td>"; 
                $out .= "<td>".$row['ItemCode']."</td>"; 
                $out .= "<td>".$row['Description']."</td>"; 
                $out .= "<td>".$row['UNIT']."</td>"; 
                $out .= "<td>".$row['QTY']."</td>"; 
                $out .= "<td>".$row['OPEN_QTY']."</td>";                 
                $out .= "<td><input type='number' id='PickQty".$r."' min='0' max =".$row['OPEN_QTY']." value =".$row['OPEN_QTY']." step='0.01' onchange='updateValue(this)'></td>";
                $out .= "<td>".$row['ShipDate']."</td>"; 
                $out .= "</tr>";
                $r+=1;
            }
            $out .= "</tbody>";
            echo $out;
        @endphp
    </table> 
    </div>
</body>

<!-- make table available for sorting -->
<script>

var table;

$(document).ready(function()
{
    table = $('#myTable').dataTable(
    {
        dom: 'Blfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copy',
            'excel',
            'pdf',            
            {
                extend: 'print',
                text: 'Print selected',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: ':visible'
                }
            },
            'colvis',
            {
                extend: 'print',
                text: 'Print all',
                exportOptions: {
                    modifier: {
                        selected: null
                    }
                }
            },            
            
            $.extend(true, {}, buttonCommon, 
            {
                extend: 'print',
                text: 'My Custom Table',
                exportOptions: { columns: ':visible'},
                autoPrint: false
            }),
            
        ],
        select: true,        
        scrollY:        '70vh',
        scrollX:       true,
        scrollCollapse: true,
        lengthMenu: [[10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]],
        pagingType: "full_numbers",
    });
});

var buttonCommon = 
{
    exportOptions: 
    {
        format: 
        {
            body: function (data, column, row, node) 
            {
                // distinguish between a regular cell and one with an input element
                if ($(node)[0].children.length === 0)
                {
                    return data;
                }
                else 
                {   
                    if(row===8)//column PickQuantity
                    {
                        var current = document.getElementById('PickQty'+String(column));  
                        return current.getAttribute("value");
                    }
                    
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

function updateValue(e) {
var current = document.getElementById(e.id);
current.setAttribute("value",e.value);
};

</script>

</html>
```

Comment: http://live.datatables.net/leqonovo/3/edit 
Take look at this example it will solve your  problem

Comment: Hi Rush, Thank you for the helpful comment. The code lack some lines that allowed users to change the value of cells. That makes me after editing the value in the input field still can not print it out. Could you please help too?

Comment: the example is using a dataset it's can't change dynamically if you want to change the dataset it's working check it out

Answer (score 0):

Here Added example change the dataset

```js
    var table;

    $(document).ready(function () {

        setHeader();
        table = $('#dttest').DataTable({
            data: dataset,
            "lengthMenu": [10, 50, 100],
            "scrollCollapse": true,
            "order": [[0, 'asc']],
            "orderClasses": false,
            "colReorder": true,
            "processing": true,
            columns: [
                { data: "ID" },
                { data: "Flag" },
                { data: "Zone", "render": input_field, "defaultContent": "" },
                { data: "Class", "render": input_field, "defaultContent": "" },
                { data: "Units" },
                { data: "Value" },
                { data: "Year" }
            ],
            "columnDefs": [
                { "orderDataType": "dom-input", "targets": [2, 3], "type": "string" }
            ],
            "buttons": [
                $.extend(true, {}, buttonCommon, {
                    extend: 'copy',
                    exportOptions: { columns: ':visible' }
                }),
                $.extend(true, {}, buttonCommon, {
                    extend: 'csv',
                    exportOptions: { columns: ':visible' }
                }),
                $.extend(true, {}, buttonCommon, {
                    extend: 'print',
                    exportOptions: { columns: ':visible' }
                }),
            ]
        });


    table.buttons().container()
    .insertAfter('#dttest_length');


    });  // end document ready

    function setHeader() {
        $tr = $('<tr>');
        $tr.append($('<th>').text("ID"));
        $tr.append($('<th>').text("Flag"));
        $tr.append($('<th>').text("Zone"));
        $tr.append($('<th>').text("Class"));
        $tr.append($('<th>').text("Units"));
        $tr.append($('<th>').text("Value"));
        $tr.append($('<th>').text("Year"));
        $tr.appendTo('#dttest thead');
    }

    var buttonCommon = {
        exportOptions: {
            format: {
                body: function (data, column, row, node) {
                    // distinguish between a regular cell and one with an input element
                    if ($(node)[0].children.length === 0){
                        return data;
                    }
                    else {
                        return $(data).val();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    var input_field = function (data, type, full, meta) {
        data = $.trim(data);
        var row = meta.row;
        var col = meta.col;
        var colName = meta.settings.aoColumns[col].data;
        return '<input class="form-control input-xs input-width-sm" maxlength="4" id="' + colName + '" name="EditItems[' + row + '].' + colName + '" value="' + data + '" type="text"/>';
    };

    // custom ordering for input columns in dataTable
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.order['dom-input'] = function (settings, col) {
        return this.api().column(col, { order: 'index' }).nodes().map(function (td, i) {
            return $('input', td).val();
        });
    };
   //**here you Need to change the input its just example**
    var dataset = [{
        "ID": 4,
        "Flag": "#A=ST",
        "Zone": null,
        "Class": "N100",
        "Units": 1.00,
        "Value": 610759.0,
        "Year": 2011
    }, {
        "ID": 5,
        "Flag": "#C",
        "Zone": null,
        "Class": "N101",
        "Units": 1.00,
        "Value": 62707.0,
        "Year": 2011
    }, {
        "ID": 6,
        "Flag": "B&G",
        "Zone": null,
        "Class": null,
        "Units": 0.00,
        "Value": 610759.0,
        "Year": 2011
    }, {
        "ID": 7,
        "Flag": "#D",
        "Zone": null,
        "Class": null,
        "Units": 1.00,
        "Value": 1308000.0,
        "Year": 2011
    }, {
        "ID": 8,
        "Flag": "#A",
        "Zone": null,
        "Class": null,
        "Units": 1.00,
        "Value": 109879.0,
        "Year": 2011
    }, {
        "ID": 9,
        "Flag": "#C",
        "Zone": null,
        "Class": "R800",
        "Units": 0.00,
        "Value": null,
        "Year": 2011
    }, {
        "ID": 10,
        "Flag": "B&G",
        "Zone": null,
        "Class": "R800",
        "Units": 1.50,
        "Value": null,
        "Year": 2011
    }, {
        "ID": 11,
        "Flag": "B&G",
        "Zone": null,
        "Class": "R800",
        "Units": 0.00,
        "Value": null,
        "Year": 2011
    }, {
        "ID": 12,
        "Flag": "#A=ST",
        "Zone": null,
        "Class": "R800",
        "Units": 2.00,
        "Value": null,
        "Year": 2011
    }, {
        "ID": 13,
        "Flag": "#A",
        "Zone": null,
        "Class": "R800",
        "Units": 0.00,
        "Value": null,
        "Year": 2011
    }, {
        "ID": 14,
        "Flag": "#A",
        "Zone": null,
        "Class": "R800",
        "Units": 0.00,
        "Value": null,
        "Year": 2011
    }, {
        "ID": 15,
        "Flag": "#D",
        "Zone": null,
        "Class": "C128",
        "Units": 0.00,
        "Value": 274505.0,
        "Year": 2011
    }, {
        "ID": 16,
        "Flag": "#A",
        "Zone": null,
        "Class": null,
        "Units": 0.00,
        "Value": 289859.0,
        "Year": 2011
    }, {
        "ID": 17,
        "Flag": "#C",
        "Zone": null,
        "Class": "C100",
        "Units": 0.00,
        "Value": 10862019.0,
        "Year": 2011
    }, {
        "ID": 18,
        "Flag": "#D",
        "Zone": null,
        "Class": "C113",
        "Units": 0.00,
        "Value": 76859.0,
        "Year": 2011
    }, {
        "ID": 19,
        "Flag": "#C",
        "Zone": null,
        "Class": null,
        "Units": 0.00,
        "Value": 1380008.0,
        "Year": 2011
    }, {
        "ID": 20,
        "Flag": "#A",
        "Zone": null,
        "Class": null,
        "Units": 0.00,
        "Value": 249750.0,
        "Year": 2011
    }, {
        "ID": 21,
        "Flag": "B&G",
        "Zone": null,
        "Class": null,
        "Units": 0.00,
        "Value": 253900.0,
        "Year": 2011
    }, {
        "ID": 22,
        "Flag": "#D",
        "Zone": null,
        "Class": "R800",
        "Units": 0.00,
        "Value": null,
        "Year": 2011
    }, {
        "ID": 23,
        "Flag": "#A",
        "Zone": null,
        "Class": null,
        "Units": 0.00,
        "Value": 677320.0,
        "Year": 2011
    }, {
        "ID": 24,
        "Flag": "#A",
        "Zone": null,
        "Class": null,
        "Units": 0.00,
        "Value": 538028.0,
        "Year": 2011
    }, {
        "ID": 25,
        "Flag": "#A",
        "Zone": null,
        "Class": null,
        "Units": 0.00,
        "Value": 75603.0,
        "Year": 2011
    }, {
        "ID": 26,
        "Flag": "#C",
        "Zone": null,
        "Class": "R800",
        "Units": 0.00,
        "Value": null,
        "Year": 2011
    }, {
        "ID": 27,
        "Flag": "#C",
        "Zone": null,
        "Class": "R100",
        "Units": 0.00,
        "Value": 325970.0,
        "Year": 2011
    }, {
        "ID": 28,
        "Flag": "#A",
        "Zone": null,
        "Class": "R200",
        "Units": 0.00,
        "Value": 250000.0,
        "Year": 2011
    }
    ];
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>DataTables Test Buttons</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/dataTables.bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/colreorder/1.3.2/css/colReorder.bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/colreorder/1.3.2/js/dataTables.colReorder.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h3>DataTables Test Buttons</h3>
            <table id="dttest" class="table-condensed table-striped table-bordered compact dataTable" cellspacing="0">
            <thead></thead>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Goodday Rush.
I have finished my requirement with another solution.
As you know I did not use the dataset but write all the data from odbc to html table and then use js to turn normal html table to yajra datatables.
So in the Input column, I set id for every cell then make an onchange event to update their values.
Thank you so much for your kindly help.